# JPA Entity and its custom features

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity Venue with its Events:

```
  Event { ID, Name, DateTime }
  Venue { ID, Name, @OneToMany List<Event> events}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to call these functions in view (with OpenEntityManagerInView):

```
  customVenue.getId(); // no problem
  customVenue.getName(); // no problem
  customVenue.getEvents(); // no problem
  customVenue.getCurrentEvents(); // hm?
  customVenue.getPastEvents(); // hm?
```

There might be thousands of events in the database, so iterating over the "events" to get the current ones might not be a good idead.

Is this a correct approach? Is this feasible? How can I split events in current and past and to have them ordered?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible. But not using a method of customVenue (unless the entity has a reference to the entity manager, which is a bad idea).

Execute a query:

```
String jpql = "select event from Venue venue"
              + " inner join venue.events event"
              + " where event.date < :now"
              + " order by event.date asc";
List<Event> pastEvents = em.createQuery(jpql, Event.class)
                           .setParameter("now", new Date())
                           .getResultList();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I am using lazy loading with OpenEntityManagerInView - and when I have a list of 20 venues, I iterate over the list directly in the view and print them. With this approach, I would have to call the database query from the view, which would break the MVC - that is probably as bad as giving the EntityManager to the Entity, or not?

Comment: The goal of the controller in MVC is to prepare the model for the view. Make it execute the appropriate queries, and prepare a `List<VenueWithPastEvents>` for the view.

Comment: Okay, I was just thinking whether this could be done in a some kind of simple way without controller. Thanks!

Comment: Actually there is probably a better way - with @JoinFormula("") and @OneToMany annotations. However the feature is not well documented and I can't find a way to write the Formula properly to serve the purpose.